# Wait onPostExecute finish to make new adapter

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I try to find some movie with the Tmdb api, but I have a problem.

I need to do an Asynctask everytime I make something on my `EditText` but the task is to longer.

This is possible to wait until onPostExecute on `fetchData` is not finish?

My fetchData class which make AsyncTask:

```java
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    //make things...
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    SearchActivity.listFinale = list;
}
```

A part of my SearchActivity:

```java
public static RecyclerView rv;
public static ArrayList<Movie> listFinale = new ArrayList<Movie>();

recherche.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                fetchData process = new fetchData(recherche.getText().toString());
                process.execute();


                //I want to do this part when onPostExecute is finish
                rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
                MyAdapter mMyadapter= new MyAdapter(listFinale);
                rv.setAdapter(mMyadapter);
                mMyadapter.setonItmeClickListener(SearchActivity.this);
               //

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you can learn retrofit, rxjava rxandroid (reactive programming) libraries. in this way, you can do communicate with an interface.
You can create an interface and implemented in SearchActivity.

```
public interface IResultListener {
  void onResult(List<BlaBlaModel> list);
}
```

then, implement in the SearchActivity.

```
private IResultListener resultListener = new IResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(List<BlaBlaModel> list) {
        // do anything...
    }
};
```

then we assign this interface object to asynctask. when result is completed, we send list to SearchActivity with interface object like this.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
     if (listener != null) {
        listener.onResult(list)
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to : change EditText -> get EditText value -> do fetchData with the value and send new list to my activity -> make new Adapter with the new list. Actually, I don't understand why you're solution will stop the Thread in the onTextChanged part, and continue after onPostExecute is finish

Comment: Android applications run UI Thread. Asynctask allows you to perform background operations. So, when you use Asynctask, process is did background with another thread. The ui thread continues to run without waiting for the other thread attachment. In your code, you call fetchData and start process, but you do not listen the result. before the result comes, the adapter can be created and re-assigned to the recyclerview.for this, I need to know that the process is over, after that I can do the necessary operations.